# How to request unix domain socket using racket

Tags: racket

I wanna build a docker wrapper, docker api requires using unix domain socket like this

```
$ curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/v1.24/images/json
```

Is there any useful pkgs in racket that can helps me out.

if that is `racket-request`, could you please give some examples to start

Answer (score 1):

Racket has built in support for unix sockets (on unix platforms anyway) You can get them by requiring the `racket/unix-socket` library: `(require racket/unix-socket)`.

Alternatively, if you can get docker to use ZeroMQ sockets, there seem to be two different Racket packages for them: `zeromq` and `zmq`, which you can get with:

```
raco pkg install zeromq
```

or

```
raco pkg install zmq
```

And then you can use the `zmq` or `net/zmq` library. I don't really know if one library is preferred over the other.

Comment: Hi, could you please give some examples how to send request and receive response using racket/unix-socket. I checked this before but didn't figure out its usage.

Comment: For zeromq, I recommend `zeromq-r` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The Racket web server lets you listen on something other than an TCP port with the [`serve` function](https://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server-internal/web-server.html#%28def._%28%28lib._web-server%2Fweb-server..rkt%29._serve%29%29)'s `#:tcp@` argument. The `racket/unix-socket-tcp-unit` module has a function, [`make-unix-socket-tcp@`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/unix-socket/index.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Funix-socket-tcp-unit..rkt%29._make-unix-socket-tcp%7E40%29%29), for creating a value of the appropriate signature to use with it.

Example using it:

```lisp
#lang racket/base

(require racket/unix-socket-tcp-unit
         web-server/http/xexpr web-server/servlet-dispatch web-server/web-server)

; Create a unix domain socket and wrap in a unit that the webserver
; can use for connections
(define socket-path (string->path "/tmp/web.sock"))
(when (file-exists? socket-path) (delete-file socket-path))
(define my-unix-socket@ (make-unix-socket-tcp@ socket-path))

; Trivial example request handler
(define (my-example req)
  (response/xexpr
   '(html
     (head (title "Hello"))
     (body (p "Hello from Racket")))))

; Serve on the unix socket instead of a tcp port
(define (my-server)
  (serve #:dispatch (dispatch/servlet my-example)
         #:tcp@ my-unix-socket@))

(module+ main
  ; Start the server and wait forever
  (define stop (my-server))
  (with-handlers ([exn:break? (lambda (e)
                                (stop))])
    (sync/enable-break never-evt)))
```

and demonstration:

```bash
$ racket unix-web.rkt &
$ curl --unix-socket /tmp/web.sock http://localhost
<html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body><p>Hello from Racket</p></body></html>
```

Comment: Better a few years late than never, I guess.